# Add 'keydown' event listener to document except for input field

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, keydown, removeeventlistener

I am creating a Hangman game with a virtual keypad and a form input section where users can guess the entire word.

I am able to add a 'keydown' event listener to the document, but I DO NOT want want the 'keydown' event to fire off if I am typing into the input field.

Here is how I've added the event listener.

`document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);`

Here is the form input.

```
<form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
          <div className="input-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              name="letter"
              placeholder="Guess the word"
              value={formWord}
              onChange={e => setFormWord(e.target.value.toUpperCase())}
              disabled={disabled}
            />

            <div className="input-group-append">
              <button
                className="btn text-white"
                type="submit"
                disabled={disabled}
              >
                <i className="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right" /> Go!
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

I've already tried using `document.getElementsByTagName[0].removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)`, but that's not working. I'm assuming that's because the event listener was added onto the actual document instead of the element.

Please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside `handleKeyDown`, only execute the body of the function if the `event.target` does not match the input field, eg:

```
const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
  if (event.target.matches('[name="letter"]')) {
    return;
  }
  // rest of function body
};
```

Comment: You are amazing! This is the simple solution that I've been looking for this whole time!!

Comment: The more general solution would be to check if `event.target.tagName?.toUpperCase() === 'INPUT'`.

Comment: @KirillRakhman I think `event.target.matches('input')` is simpler. Thanks for the idea. 